# Unsupported Photos Library, Update Photos

Tags: photos

I tried to open Photos and got this message:
The library "Photos Library" is from a newer version of Photos.
Please upgrade Photos to open this library.

When I do this, there are no photos. All gone. I looked in Pictures and see Photo Library and
Photo Library 2.  I look in Get Info for both. The original Photo Library shows 35GB. The Photo Library 2 shows 2.5MB. But when I click on Photo Library (original, 35GB) I get the above message.

I did reinstall Mojave beforehand for another reason. I have iMac Mojave.

What should I do now?

Comment: Was the version of macOS before you installed Mojave (I assume the last version) *later* than Mojave (Catalina or Big Sur) ? If so you will need to install whatever version was there previously unless you don't care about the meta data and edits.

Comment: I don't know what happened but you can still access your content. If you open the Photos Library file in finder (usually located in photos folder), right click on it and select show contents of this package. In the originals folder you find more folders with your pictures and videos.